# How to mention token based sonar server URL in hygieia-codequality-sonar-collector application..properties

Tags: sonarqube, token, collectors, hygieia

I have created Hygieia dashboard and trying to configure sonar project. I have followed below  hygieia-codequality-sonar-collector document and running sonar collector.

https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia/blob/gh-pages/pages/hygieia/collectors/build/sonar.md

Instead of sonar.usernames and sonar.passwords, I have given sonar.tokens[0]= details in application.properies. But, getting the below login error.

```
ERROR c.c.d.collector.DefaultSonar6Client - org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401
2022-08-16 04:19:00,304 [taskScheduler-1] ERROR c.c.d.collector.SonarCollectorTask - org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401
2022-08-16 04:19:00,304 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  c.c.d.collect
```

```
# Database Name
        dbname=dashboarddb

        # Database HostName - default is localhost
        dbhost=localhost

        # Database Port - default is 27017
        dbport=27017

        # MongoDB replicaset
        dbreplicaset=[false if you are not using MongoDB replicaset]
        dbhostport=[host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3]

        # Database Username - default is blank
        dbusername=dashboarduser

        # Database Password - default is blank
        dbpassword=dbpassword

        # Collector schedule (required)
        sonar.cron=0 0/5 * * * *

        # Sonar server(s) (required) - Can provide multiple
        sonar.servers[0]=https://abc.company.com
        
        # Sonar version, match array index to the server. If not set, will default to version prior to 6.3.
        sonar.versions[0]=8.6
        
        # Sonar Metrics - Required. 
        #Sonar versions lesser than 6.3
        
        # Sonar tokens to connect to authenticated url 
        sonar.tokens[0]=xxxxxxxxx
        #sonar.metrics[0]=ncloc,line_coverage,violations,critical_violations,major_violations,blocker_violations,violations_density,sqale_index,test_success_density,test_failures,test_errors,tests
        
        # For Sonar version 6.3 and above
        sonar.metrics[0]=ncloc,violations,new_vulnerabilities,critical_violations,major_violations,blocker_violations,tests,test_success_density,test_errors,test_failures,coverage,line_coverage,sqale_index,alert_status,quality_gate_details
        
        # Sonar login credentials
        # Format: username1,username2,username3,etc.
        #sonar.usernames= 
        # Format: password1,password2,password3,etc.
        #sonar.passwords=
```

Please help me on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed token based sonar login issue after updated `sonar.servers[0]` URL

Correct application.properties file:

```
# Database Name
        dbname=dashboarddb

        # Database HostName - default is localhost
        dbhost=localhost

        # Database Port - default is 27017
        dbport=27017

        # MongoDB replicaset
        dbreplicaset=[false if you are not using MongoDB replicaset]
        dbhostport=[host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3]

        # Database Username - default is blank
        dbusername=dashboarduser

        # Database Password - default is blank
        dbpassword=dbpassword

        # Collector schedule (required)
        sonar.cron=0 0/5 * * * *

        # Sonar server(s) (required) - Can provide multiple
         sonar.servers[0]=https://api-token@abc.company.com
        
        # Sonar version, match array index to the server. If not set, will default to version prior to 6.3.
        sonar.versions[0]=8.6
        
        # Sonar Metrics - Required. 
        #Sonar versions lesser than 6.3
        
        # Sonar tokens to connect to authenticated url 
        sonar.tokens[0]=xxxxxxxxx
        #sonar.metrics[0]=ncloc,line_coverage,violations,critical_violations,major_violations,blocker_violations,violations_density,sqale_index,test_success_density,test_failures,test_errors,tests
        
        # For Sonar version 6.3 and above
        sonar.metrics[0]=ncloc,violations,new_vulnerabilities,critical_violations,major_violations,blocker_violations,tests,test_success_density,test_errors,test_failures,coverage,line_coverage,sqale_index,alert_status,quality_gate_details
        
        # Sonar login credentials
        # Format: username1,username2,username3,etc.
        #sonar.usernames= 
        # Format: password1,password2,password3,etc.
        #sonar.passwords=
```

Thank you.